# How to estimate the complexity of a variational quantum circuit？

Tags: complexity-theory

How to estimate the complexity of a variational quantum circuit? For example, I have a quantum circuit of $n$ qubits that uses alternating operators to build the network and train it. So what is the complexity of this circuit?

Comment: To be more specific, what type of complexity are you interested in — e.g. gate complexity, qubit complexity?

Comment: The complexity I need is a measure of quantum advantage. In addition, I am also curious about various complexities. What is the meaning of indicators such as gate complexity?